# Accommodating Web App Data in Android App

Tags: android, database, schema

1. Whenever user signs in/up to the Android App, we need to show some content which is dynamic(Ex. posts by other people) and coming from Web App. Do we need to store some of these posts in local database, so that user can see the posts instantly whenever he/she opens the App?
2. If yes, then how can we accommodate them in our local database?. Post by the user can be video, link, Image or Text.  Do we need to design separate schema for each type of the post?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store the same data in your local database as well. Just update your local database with latest contents from web app. so that each time when user starts app, latest contents get loaded to local one.

Other option is to give user choice to refresh the contents on pull or something like that as in **G MAIL** and **FACEBOOK** . Please have a look on pull to refresh library.

[Pull To Refresh for Android](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)